# How to use shell variable in MQTT

Tags: json, linux, shell

I am new to shell scripting and MQTT.
I need to publish a `JSON file` using `MQTT`. We can do it by storing the JSON contents in a `shell variable`. But it is not working for me.

my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

var1='{"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"4TSJhIZmL0A","uploaded":"2008-07-15T18:11:59.000Z","updated":"2013-05-01T21:01:49.000Z","uploader":"burloandbardsey","category":"News","title":"bbc news start up theme","description":"bbc","thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4TSJhIZmL0A/default.jpg","hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4TSJhIZmL0A/hqdefault.jpg"},"player":{"default":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TSJhIZmL0A&feature=youtube_gdata_player","mobile":"http://m.youtube.com/details?v=4TSJhIZmL0A"},"content":{"5":"http://www.youtube.com/v/4TSJhIZmL0A?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata","1":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlAL2aGhIk04RMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp","6":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlAL2aGhIk04RMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"},"duration":15,"aspectRatio":"widescreen","rating":4.6683936,"likeCount":"354","ratingCount":386,"viewCount":341066,"favoriteCount":0,"commentCount":155,"accessControl":{"comment":"allowed","commentVote":"allowed","videoRespond":"allowed","rate":"allowed","embed":"allowed","list":"allowed","autoPlay":"allowed","syndicate":"allowed"}}}'
mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t test -m "$var1"
echo "$var1"
```

my Mosquitto commands:
Publisher: `mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t "test" -m "{"Contents":$var1}"

Subscriber: `mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t "test"`

Output I got:
`{"Contents":}`

Expected Output:
`{"Contents":{"name":"Harini", "age":24, "city":"NewYork", "message":"Hello world"}}`

I can get the output only at the terminal because of echo. But I want to publish and subscribe to the contents of the shell variable(var1)

Please help me out to get the output. Whether I need to add some more code in the shell script. I don't know how to proceed. Or can you suggest any other method.

Comment: The declaration for `var1` won't work without escaping the internal `"` or swapping the wrapping double quotes to single quotes

Comment: That edit hasn't changed the wrapping quotes as in my example. Also I asked for the WHOLE script, the `mosquitto_pub` is missing.

Comment: But I executed with the wrapping quotes you suggested. Forgot to update here

Comment: Still missing the `mosquitto_pub` command from the script!

Comment: That's my script

Comment: No it's not, copy and paste your ACTUAL script! What you've put in the question doesn't run because it has typos in it. (with the typos fixed that script works perfectly)

Comment: I copy pasted it

Comment: Assuming the double `#` at the start and the trailing `~` is a mistake.... That script does exactly what you want

Comment: No that's a typo error. it's not working still

Comment: I've just copy and pasted the script as is now (which is right) and it works just fine. I'm done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works just fine, it's all about which quotes you use where:

```
#!/bin/sh
var1='{"name":"Harini", "age":24, "city":"NewYork","message":"Hello world"}'
echo $var1

mosquitto_pub -t test -m "{\"Content\": $var1}"
```

You need to wrap the `-m` argument in quotes because it contains spaces, which in turn means you need to escape the `"` round `Content`.

Wrapping the content of `var1` in single quotes means you don't need to escape the double quotes in it.

Comment: It's not working. I saved the script with a filename (eg: filename.sh). Was it the problem for not working.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what you call it as long it has the execute bit set, that example script does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Yeah, I changed the script as you suggested but it's not working. Still, I get the output {"Content":}. What may be the issue?

Comment: Edit the question to show your actual script (all of it)

Comment: I have edited the Question, that's all I added to my script. A variable to store and echo command to display it in the terminal

Comment: As soon as your script finishes, the $var1 variable is discarded. If you want to use it after the script is called, you have to put it into a variable in that shell. For example var2=$(bash filename.sh), then you can use $var2 in your mqtt command.